# Custom auth module in ejabberd 17.07

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-auth

In ejabberd 16.02, I had a custom authentication module working.  It was named `ejabberd_auth_component.beam`, and placed into the proper directory.  Then, I set `auth_method: component` in the config.  ejabberd would then use the custom module (provided it implemented the correct functions).

This no longer works in ejabberd 17.07.  ejabberd now ignores `auth_method: component` as an invalid option type.  Is there a way to get custom auth modules working in 17.07?  I've been perusing the updated codebase, but have yet to find a way to add new auth methods.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have all (non optional) callbacks properly defined in your module: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/17.07/src/ejabberd_auth.erl#L70
2. Make sure you have `-behaviour(ejabberd_auth).` compiler directive in your module.